# HTML & CSS 3 spans different meaning in anchor or using position to make it "right"?

Tags: html, css, seo, css-position

**EDIT:**
What if instead the date, I need description? (than I should use paragraph, and for validation paragraph cant be in anchor because paragraph is a block level)
**End of EDIT**

I believe that you didn't understand what I want by reading the title.
I wasn't sure how write one sentence that will summary my question.

So, this is my question:
I have anchor with 3 different things inside it > icon, title and date. each is in different span.
I dont know if its the right method to make it.

```
<ul id="m-items">
    <li>
        <a href="/post.php?name=ahf-_" class="m-item-header clear">
            <span class="m-item-icon"></span>
            <span class="m-item-title">ah%f#-$%^&amp;()_!</span>
            <span class="m-item-date">17 Feb 2013</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/post.php?name=d-3" class="m-item-header clear">
            <span class="m-item-icon"></span>
            <span class="m-item-title">d-3</span>
            <span class="m-item-date">16 Feb 2013</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[full jsfiddle of the code above](http://jsfiddle.net/FeMZN/)

I got another method to do it, which I think is the right method but I am not sure...
My second method is using div with two elements, anchor and another div that contains the text.
Each will be in absolute position.

```
<ul id="m-items">
    <li>
        <div class="m-item-header">
            <a href="/post.php?name=ahf-_"></a>
            <div class="m-item-header-content clear">
                <div class="m-item-icon"></div>
                <div class="m-item-title">ah%f#-$%^&amp;()_!</div>
                <div class="m-item-date">17 Feb 2013</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="m-item-header">
            <a href="/post.php?name=d-3"></a>
            <div class="m-item-header-content clear">
                <div class="m-item-icon"></div>
                <span class="m-item-title">d-3</span>
                <span class="m-item-date">16 Feb 2013</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[full jsfiddle of the code above](http://jsfiddle.net/eeXyB/1/)

I would like to know which method is the right one and why (both for SEO and for HTML itself).

**EDIT:**
What if instead the date, I need description? (than I should use paragraph, and for validation paragraph cant be in anchor because paragraph is a block level)
**End of EDIT**

~Thanks

Comment: Both are great I presume, I'll keep the first one, less `divs` and prettier code :).

Comment: We have a `time` element:  http://html5doctor.com/the-time-element/

Comment: @cimmanon don't care about html5.

Comment: Whether or not you care about HTML5 is irrelevant when it comes to SEO:  it matters what the search engines care about.  If Google cares about the `time` tag, you're shooting yourself in the foot by not using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty much up to your taste.

I would prefer the first one due to the following reasons:

- lesser markup -> better overview and maintanability and lesser filesize
- no absolute positioning - should be avoided wherever possible (performance and robustness of code)
- semantically more clear - the elements belong to the link (if this is the case for your markup)

From the SEO perspective the first solution is clearly better, becaue it correlation between the elements and the link is clear, while it's not for the second code example.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the SEO implications are (if there are indeed any at all), but the two have differing implications for your site behavior.

That anchor tag in the second example is going to be unclickable.  Without some kind of content inside it, it will appear as nothing to users, and the navigation aspect which you're trying to achieve (as evidenced by an href that points to another page) will not work.

**Edit**

That's what I get for not looking at the fiddle first.  Yes, the above is wrong, you're achieving this by layering your anchor over other content.  I'll agree with the above poster that keeping your content wrapped in the anchor element is correct semantically, and that's what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is *right*, but then neither is *wrong*. I would strongly favour the first one from a usability point of view, as the item data is all wrapped within the link, so is more navigable.

Answer (score 0):

For SEO purposes and also for the best practice use of anchor tags and what you are trying to achieve the second one is "wrong" on the basis that the div and the two spans are not contained within the anchor tag.

That said, you should definitely go with the first one as its more semantically clear and readable, I understand whats going on there with minimal effort.  In addition to that the spans are all contained inside the anchor tag, which is syntactically correct both for SEO and HTML proper usage.

I can't particularly think of another way to do this other than using a UL and a LI and making your icon the replacement for the "bullet" point.